# Retrieve Secrets from GCP

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I followed the GCP documentation: (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets) for retrieving Secrets.

The only difference is that I am running the application with the Spring framework so my main module starts with a main and Spring Application lines of code.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error with the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main"
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to
obtain metadata     at
com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:67)
    at
com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at
com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at
com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:67)   at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1132)
    at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
    at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1270)
    at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1038)
    at
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:808)
    at
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
    at
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
    at
io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at
io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at
io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at
com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:535)
    at
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:743)
    at
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:722)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)    at
io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:858)  Suppressed:
com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at
com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at
com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.accessSecretVersion(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:1279)
        at
com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.accessSecretVersion(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:1215)
        at
com.recontool.readSecrets.AccessSecretVersion.accessSecretVersion(AccessSecretVersion.java:39)
        at
com.recontool.readSecrets.AccessSecretVersion.main(AccessSecretVersion.java:25)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials
failed to obtain metadata   at
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.fillInStackTrace(StatusRuntimeException.java:68)
    at
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:58)
    at
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:50)
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)   ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target     at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1505)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:578)
    at
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
    at
java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
    at
com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
    at
com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at
com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials.doRefreshAccessToken(UserCredentials.java:277)
    at
com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials.refreshAccessToken(UserCredentials.java:191)
    at
com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:257)
    at
com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:254)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 3 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target   at
java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:388)
    at
java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:271)
    at
java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:256)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at
java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1335)
    ... 27 more Caused by:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target   at
java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at
java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at
java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at
java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383)
    ... 32 more
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
David

Code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessSecretVersion.class, args);
        String projectId = ..
        String String secretId = ..
        String versionId = "2";
        accessSecretVersion(projectId, secretId, versionId);
    }
    
    public static void accessSecretVersion(String projectId, String secretId, String versionId)
            throws IOException {
        // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
        // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
        // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
        try (SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create()) {
            SecretVersionName secretVersionName = SecretVersionName.of(projectId, secretId, versionId);

            // Access the secret version.
            AccessSecretVersionResponse response = client.accessSecretVersion(secretVersionName);

            // Verify checksum. The used library is available in Java 9+.
            // If using Java 8, you may use the following:
            // https://github.com/google/guava/blob/e62d6a0456420d295089a9c319b7593a3eae4a83/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.java#L395
            byte[] data = response.getPayload().getData().toByteArray();
            Checksum checksum = new CRC32C();
            checksum.update(data, 0, data.length);
            if (response.getPayload().getDataCrc32C() != checksum.getValue()) {
                System.out.printf("Data corruption detected.");
                return;
            }

            // Print the secret payload.
            //
            // WARNING: Do not print the secret in a production environment - this
            // snippet is showing how to access the secret material.
            String payload = response.getPayload().getData().toStringUtf8();
            System.out.printf("Plaintext: %s\n", payload);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you running your code? As well can you share a little snippet of your code? So far thee issue seems to be with Authentication

Comment: Can you share more piece of code?

Comment: I am running my code from within IntelliJ.